# Get all numbers within a string c# regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, int

I have a string which can have values like
"Barcode :  X 2
 4688000000000"

"Barcode :  X 10
 1234567890123"

etc.

I want to retrieve the quantity value (i.e., 2, 10) and the barcode value (i.e., 4688000000000, 1234567890123)

I tried the following code -

```
string[] QtyandBarcode = Regex.Split(NPDVariableMap.NPDUIBarcode.DisplayText, @"\D+");
```

But when I execute, I'm getting QtyandBarcode as a string array having 3 values - 
""
"2"
"4688000000000"

How do I prevent the null value from being stored?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve 2 and 4688000000000 from "Barcode : X 2 4688000000000" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] QtyandBarcode = Regex.Split(NPDVariableMap.NPDUIBarcode.DisplayText, @"\D+").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

now you can

```
string qty = QtyandBarcode[0];
string barcode= QtyandBarcode[1];
```

Comment: This isn't working. I'm getting an error saying "string[] doesn't contain a definition for 'Where'"

Comment: You need `Linq`, add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(NPDVariableMap.NPDUIBarcode.DisplayText, @"\d+");

var x = (from Match a in m select a.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple approach.

```
string[] parts =  NPDVariableMap.NPDUIBarcode.DisplayText.split(' ');  //split on space
string qty = parts[1];
string barcode = parts[2];
```

Comment: The string syntax could change in future and I want only the numbers to be captured.